# Rewrite URL with ID to one file using .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, apache, url-rewriting

I have "home" directory as:

```
/var/www/page
```

I need redirect:

```
/var/www/page/index/product/id/9098890
```

Where `9098890` is the *id* of *product*.

to one file:

```
/var/www/page/script/index.php
```

I want everyone who writes in web browser:

```
http://example.com/index/product/id/(ANY ID)
```

to be redirected to script:

```
http://example.com/script/index.php
```

How to do it with `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 1):

> i need redirect:

To clarify, what you need is an *internal* URL "rewrite" (the URL in the browser's address bar does not change), not strictly a "redirect", which would imply an *external* "redirect" (an additional HTTP request).

Try something like the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file in the document root (which I assume is `/var/www/page/.htaccess`) using mod_rewrite:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index/product/id/\d+$ script/index.php [L]
```

Where your "ANY ID" is 1 or more digits at the end of the URL-path.

**UPDATE:** You can then extract the *id* by parsing the `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']` (or `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`) superglobal in your PHP script. (But note that `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` also potentially contains a query string.)

Alternatively, you can explicitly pass the *id* to your script, as @StephenOstermiller mentioned in comments. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^index/product/id/(\d+)$ script/index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

You could then access the *id* value using PHP's `$_GET['id']`.

The `QSA` flag is necessary if you are expecting any additional query string parameters on the original request URL, in order to *append* them to the rewritten URL.

Comment: I'd imagine that `index.php` needs access to the ID to be able to work.   `RewriteRule ^index/product/id/(\d+)$ script/index.php?id=$1 [L]`

Comment: Awesome - very good work. I have one more trouble... because if i do rewrite it by .htaccess than requested url is show like its destiantion http:// ... script/index.php. Worst is i need id of that product to use in script (where he is rewrited). I was expect after redirect i will get requested url by something like this: $actual_link = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; but it not show where from someone come so /product/id/"number" but this directive says /script/index.php

Comment: For now i have in .htaccess: Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index/product/id/(\d+)$ script/index.php?id=$1 [L] and i dont know how to get to /srcipt/index.php this ID from oryginal link

Comment: And one more information: in webbrowser i have in address: http://domain/index/product/id/(number) but rewrite works cause its show what is in script: /script/index.php

Comment: Ok i track it myself: code: $id = $_GET['id'] . Works thank you very mutch

Comment: You should not be seeing `index.php` in the address bar (if that is what you are saying), unless perhaps you have a conflict with other directives? You can extract the _id_ by parsing the `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']` variable in PHP, or you can explicitly pass the _id_ to your script as suggested by @StephenOstermiller. I'll update my answer.

Comment: If this answered your question then please mark it as accepted (checkmark below the voting arrows on the left) to remove it from the unanswered question queue and to help other readers. Once you have 15+ rep you can also upvote answers you find useful. Thanks, much appreciated. :)